# displaying image with zoom functionality of built in android app

Tags: android

I am trying to display downloaded image in gallery built in application in Android. But I am facing problem to store and remove images from sdcard. but i am able to play songs with out storing songs by using MediaPlayer.

Like MediaPlayer class ,is there any direct class to render url images to get direct functionality with zoom in and out?

Comment: put your code... and explain you need to show image or download image and save it..

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below my code to display image with zoom functionality.

```
public class AndroidZoomActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";

    // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im_card);

         view.setImageBitmap((getBitmap("Here ImageURL")));
         view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

     ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
     view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
     float scale;

     dumpEvent(event);
     // Handle touch events here...

     switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first finger down only
     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
     Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
     mode = DRAG;
     break;

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

     mode = NONE;
     Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
     break;

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

     oldDist = spacing(event);
     Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
     if (oldDist > 5f) {
     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     midPoint(mid, event);
     mode = ZOOM;
     Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
     }
     break;

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

     if (mode == DRAG) {
     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
     matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
     - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix
     // of points
     } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
     // pinch zooming
     float newDist = spacing(event);
     Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
     if (newDist > 5f) {
     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
     scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
     // matrix...if scale > 1 means
     // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
     // zoom out
     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
     }
     }
     break;
     }

     view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

     return true; // indicate event was handled
     }

     /*
     *
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */

     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
     float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
     float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
     return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
     }

     /*
     *
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

     private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
     float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
     float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
     point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
     }

     /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
     private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
     "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     int action = event.getAction();
     int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
     sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

     if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
     || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
     sb.append("(pid ").append(
     action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
     sb.append(")");
     }

     sb.append("[");
     for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
     sb.append("#").append(i);
     sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
     sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
     sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
     if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
     sb.append(";");
     }

     sb.append("]");
     Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
     }

     /**
      * Finctionality for concerting imageURl string into bitmap
      * @param url
      * @return
      */
    public static Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bm;
    }

    static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
            super(inputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
            while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                    int b = read();
                    if (b < 0) {
                        break; // we reached EOF
                    } else {
                        bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                    }
                }
                totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
            }
            return totalBytesSkipped;
        }
    }

}
```

I hope now you got the expected Zoom functionality code.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in built. You will need an image loading implementation and an implementation of pinch zoom.

The following two are what I can personally recommend.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

and

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

```
public class ImageViewerActivity extends Activity {

public static final String EXTRA_URL = ImageViewerActivity.class.getName() + ".EXTRA_URL";

private ImageView mImageView;

private PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_viewer_activity);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

    //retrieve image url from extras
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);

    //The MAGIC happens here!
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(url, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            mAttacher.update();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Need to call clean-up
    mAttacher.cleanup();
}
}
```

and the layout...

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</merge>
```